# Exporting 2 address lines - eliminating line feed error

Tags: data-export

Mailer service provider here... 
We have regular problems with data coming from SalesForce users. Your software is intended to support only a single street address line. But against your advice, some people end up making a second custom address line. 
When this data is exported as a single address line - it throws an extra/bad line feed into the data that FUBARS everything when trying to use mailing software. The issue can be seen if you save the file as TXT and open it into a text editor.

What does the user need to do to export it correctly? I assume "Apt 3061" was entered as a second line - in the CSV you will see there is no space between the street and the apt.

Comment: Deanna, welcome to SFSE. We are a community knowledge base, not Salesforce support, and we are open to the public. I have removed your image because it appeared to contain real PII.

Answer (score 2):

The premise of this question is incorrect.

> [Salesforce] software is intended to support only a single street address line.

Salesforce's native address fields support multiple lines in street addresses:

[image: Address image]

That data, when exported, would include a line feed.

Some orgs may *also* have custom fields representing multiline addresses, something which would vary from org to org, and orgs might or might not choose to concatenate those lines with a line feed in various contexts.

Because Salesforce is a customizable database platform, there is no single set of instructions that would apply to all customers for ensuring that addresses have only a single line.

Answer (score 1):

This is an import problem, not an export problem. Try using Open Office or another spreadsheet program (e.g. Google Sheets), and you should see the appropriate line breaks. Microsoft Excel is notorious for screwing up line breaks, number formats, and more.

Also, the data isn't broken; a cell can be delimited by quotes (`"`), and line breaks can occur within. This is documented behavior, as per [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180). If the line break were misinterpreted, it would appear as the first cell on the next line. The fact that this didn't happen means that Microsoft Excel decided to remove the line break for some reason.

If mailing software doesn't support embedded line breaks, that's the software's problem. Salesforce is fully RFC 4180 compliant, and all programs that can import CSVs should also be RFC 4180 compliant. If not, that's the software's problem. You may want to log a bug to have this behavior fixed if there's a problem.